# Exclude multiple senders in gmail filter

Tags: email, filter, gmail, gmail-api

I've been trying to set up a Gmail filter which should include all mail that was CC'ed to user A, but **not** those emails which are also addressed to user B or C (or both of them).

In other words, I want the filter to select emails that were sent only to user A, but if it was also sent to anyone else on the team (B or C), it should not select them.

This is what I was trying to write, but it didn't work:

```
A@gmail.com -{B@gmail.com or C@gmail.com}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This what I did and it worked fine:

```
A@gmail.com -{B@gmail.com} -{C@gmail.com}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may refer with this [forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/WOhIBDHGTr0). Try removing the unwanted label manually from the already labeled emails. Also based from this [thread](https://www.quora.com/In-gmail-search-is-it-possible-to-exclude-other-recipients-from-a-single-or-a-list-of-recipients), if you want to exclude emails sent to `C@gmail.com` from a search, the syntax you would be using would be `-to:'c@gmail.com'`.